# When are homology groups the trivial group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've noticed that all the spaces $X$ whose (singular) homology I've computed or seen computed have $H_n(X)=0$ whenever $n$ is greater than the dimension of $X$. So I have the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture.** Suppose $n$ is the least integer such that a space $X$ may be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then for all $m >n$ we have $H_m(X)=0$.

Is this true?

Comment: Note that some spaces cannot be embedded in any $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for example $\mathbb{R}^\infty$). The way your conjecture is phrased, you're assuming the $n$ always exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is false, and somewhat surprising. There is a counterexample due to [Milnor and Barrat](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-02/S0002-9939-1962-0137110-9/) . The space is a union of a nested sequence of spheres embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and it has infinitely many non-zero singular homology groups. The nesting of the spheres is similar as in the Hawaiian earring.

However, the result is true if one imposes local niceness on the space $X$, e.g. if $X$ is a subcomplex of an $n$-dimensional CW-complex.